# Code java read tag rfid with raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I want to read tag from RFID use Raspberry pi and code java. But now I do not know how to do it. People help me! Tks very much!

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. You should include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read How to Ask- http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What frequency RFID are you working with?  What RFID reader are you working with? Do you just want raw data off tags, or something more user friendly?

Comment: I want to connect RFID (RC522) with Raspberry Pi and read RFID tag code using pure java code.

Comment: Do not use python!